# How to Access web page TextBox from another class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, textbox, controls

I have a web page called Default.aspx and a textbox called textBox1

In the Default.aspx.cs, I can set the text by typing:

```
TextBox1.text = "change text";
```

Now I have created another class. How do I call textBox1 in this class? so I want to change the text for textBox1 in this class.

So far i tried like this it is working fine in Mymethod but it is not working in Myclass.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Drawing; 
 using System.Threading;

 namespace WebApplication1
 {
 public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
 {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void submitEventMethod2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Mymethod();
    }
    public void mymethod1()
    {
       TextBox1.Text = "some text";

    }
    class Myclass
    {
     public void mymethod2()
     {
       TextBox1.Text = "some text";
     }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a web page called Default.aspx and a textbox called textBox1

In the Default.aspx.cs, I can set the text by typing:

TextBox1.text = "change text";
Now I have created another class. How do I call textBox1 in this class? so I want to change the text for textBox1 in this class.

So far i tried like this it is working fine in Mymethod but it is not working in Myclass.

using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Drawing; 
     using System.Threading;

```
 namespace WebApplication1
 {
 public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
 {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void submitEventMethod2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Mymethod();
    }
    public void mymethod1()
    {
      Myclass myClass=new Myclass ();
      myClass.mymethod2(TextBox1);

    }
    class Myclass
    {
     public void mymethod2(TextBox textBox)
     {
       textBox.Text = "some text";
     }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: hey i am still getting error for `this.textBox1 = "some text";` error is `name textBox1 does not exist in the current context`.

Comment: It  should compile now, I don't see any error in the code

Comment: Sorry I posted my question wrongly.i edited right now.please can you recheck.thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `Session[]` for this.

e.g.

```
TextBox1.Text="abc"; 
Session["TextBox_Text"]=TextBox1.Text;
```

and in other class use this Session[] to assigning text to another TextBox by using,

```
TextBox2.Text=Session["TextBox_Text"].ToString();
```

Hope this will help you

Thank You.

Comment: it gives me an error at this statement`Session("TextBox_Text")=TextBox1.Text;`

Comment: Ooppss, I am really sorry for my syntax of Session its Session[] not Session() . i apologise for this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `TextBox` `Text` like this in class. You can access it like this as well:

```
class Myclass
{   
   private string _myText;
   public string mystring
   {
      get 
      {
         return _myText;
      }
      set 
      {
         _myText = value;
      }
   }
}
public void Mymethod()
{
   Myclass obj = new Myclass();
   obj.mystring = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
   //do what else you want
}
```

Comment: Sorry I posted my question wrongly.i edited right now.please can you recheck.thank you

Answer (score 0):

create another class

```
public class DataAccess
{
 private string _value;

public string value
    {
        get
        {
            return this._value;
        }
        set
        {
            this._value = value.Trim();
        }
    }

}
```

> use these code in your aspx.cs page and create  object   DataAccess
>   class. so you can access textbox value.

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
        DataAccess objDaAccess = new DataAccess();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void submitEventMethod2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Mymethod();
        }
        public void Mymethod()
        {
           TextBox1.Text = "some text";
           objDaAccess.value=TextBox1.Text;
        }
    class Myclass
    {
       TextBox1.Text = objDaAccess.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i am trying to access TextBox1 from mymethod2 and mymethod2 is defined within Myclass I tried your solution but it is giving me error when i put  `TextBox1.Text = objDaAccess.value;` in mymethod2

Comment: use session   Session["memberid"]=TextBox1.Text and access in your class like string value= Session["memberid"].tostring();